# Google Fit Recording API not recording my Samsung Galaxy 4 Steps

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

I have connected my Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 to my phone, and created an app for my phone to trigger the Google Recording API from my phone, but it is not reading any steps data when I call Google History API, is the data delay or the watch actually not uploading data to Google Fit Cloud Server?

I tried to avoid using companion APP, because this will increase the steps to configure for users, any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's not enough info here to troubleshoot. Try to isolate the issue one at a time and see if you can notice any patterns that could help reproduce the conditions. So there's a lot of groundwork needed to rule out some of the moving parts and find out exactly where the error is originating